# TypeError: object of type 'enumerate' has no len()

Tags: python, enumerate

Here is my code:

```
def twosum(a, t):
    a = enumerate(a)
    f, l = 0, len(a)-1
    while(f <= l):
        if (a[f][1] + a[l][1] == t):
            return [a[f][0], a[l][0]]
        else:
            f += 1
            l -= 1
    return

print(twosum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'enumerate' has no len()
```

I thought we can treat enumerate objects as lists. I found solutions online that treats enumerate objects like lists. Can anybody please explain why I get this error?

Comment: treating them like lists does not necessarily mean they have the `len` attributes. Technically you could convert to list, then subset accordingly.. Also, you could set `f,l = 0,len(a)-1` before you convert a to an enumerate class

Comment: `enumerate` objects are **not** like `list`s, they are iterables. Iterables don't have to support `len` as they can be endless.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` just adds a counter to an iterable, it is **not** an iterable. enumerate objects can be converted to list, and can then be used.

As for your problem, a non-enumerate solution can be

```
def twosum(a, t):
    f, l = 0, len(a) - 1
    while f <= l:
        if a[f] + a[l] == t:
            return [a.index(a[f]), a.index(a[l])]
        else:
            f += 1
            l -= 1
twosum([2, 7, 11, 15], 17)
```

This returns [0, 3]. For an enumerate solution,

```
def twosum(a, t):
    f, l = 0, len(a)-1
    a = list(enumerate(a))
    while(f <= l):
        if (a[f][1] + a[l][1] == t):
            return [a[f][0], a[l][0]]
        else:
            f += 1
            l -= 1
twosum([2, 7, 11, 15], 17)
```

This also returns [0, 3]

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: object of type 'enumerate' has no len()
```

The [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#len) function requires objects to have or to implement the [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) function.

> `object.__len__(self)`
>
> Called to implement the built-in function `len()`. Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0.

Unfortunately, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate) returns an **enumerate object** which does not have `__len__`:

```
>>> a = enumerate([1,2,3])
>>> a
<enumerate object at 0x10e496be0>
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',
 '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
 '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__',
 '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Unlike `list`'s which supports `len()`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> dir(a)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', 
 ...
 '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__',  
 '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', 
 ...
 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

You can also notice that the **enumerate object** also does not have the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method which allows you to access items using `obj[index]` like for `list'`s. Which is why you said in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162250/2745495) that "*it isn't even subscriptable*".

> I thought we can treat enumerate objects as lists.

No, not really. An **enumerate object** behaves more like an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), which is Python's way of representing a "*stream of data*" that may be possibly infinite. You access the data by calling the `next()` method until an exception (`StopIteration`) is raised.

> Repeated calls to the iterator’s `__next__()` method (or passing it to
>   the built-in function `next()`) return successive items in the stream.
>   When no more data are available a `StopIteration` exception is raised
>   instead.

```
>>> a = enumerate([1,2,3])
>>> next(a)
(0, 1)
>>> next(a)
(1, 2)
>>> next(a)
(2, 3)
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

I think you are getting the idea that they are like `list`'s because you can also put them into a looping construct like a regular `list` and iterate over each element:

```
>>> a = enumerate([1,2,3])
>>> for i in a:
...   print(i)
... 
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
```

In this case, for each iteration, the **enumerate object** provides a tuple containing the index of the next element and the element itself. The `for` loop works and ends the same way as when you use the `next()` method of the **enumerate object**.

As shown in the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate) docs, you can simply just cast it into a `list` if you need something to be list-like:

```
>>> a = list(enumerate([1,2,3]))
>>> a
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked. I had to convert the enumerate object into a list first. Otherwise it wasn't even subscriptable.

```
def twosum(a, t):
    a = enumerate(a)
    a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1])
    f, l = 0, len(a)-1
    while(f < l):
        if (a[f][1] + a[l][1] == t):
            return [a[f][0], a[l][0]]
        elif (a[f][1] + a[l][1] < t):
            f += 1
        else:
            l -= 1
```

Comment: @cricket_007 `a` is a list. It's in the question. Or do you mean what it represents?

Comment: It was not in the original post due to the formatting, my bad

Comment: @cricket_007 Ohhh, the parameter. Right, I just fixed that.